# SVG path inside circle

Tags: svg

I would like to achieve the following using an inline SVG:

[image: SVG path within circle]

My rocket shape has been drawn like so:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon">                        
    <path id="icon" d="M11.933 13.069c0 0 7.059-5.094 6.276-10.924-0.017-0.127-0.059-0.213-0.112-0.268-0.054-0.055-0.137-0.098-0.263-0.115-5.697-0.801-10.674 6.422-10.674 6.422-4.318-0.517-4.004 0.344-5.974 5.076-0.377 0.902 0.234 1.213 0.904 0.959 0.67-0.252 2.148-0.811 2.148-0.811l2.59 2.648c0 0-0.546 1.514-0.793 2.199s0.055 1.311 0.938 0.926c4.624-2.016 5.466-1.694 4.96-6.112zM12.942 7.153c-0.598-0.613-0.598-1.604 0-2.217 0.598-0.611 1.567-0.611 2.166 0s0.598 1.603 0 2.217c-0.599 0.611-1.569 0.611-2.166 0z"></path>
</svg>
```

What's the best way to place my path within a filled circle as illustrated in the above image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with good old CSS.

```css
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    stroke-width: 0;
    stroke: currentColor;
    fill: #fff;
    background-color: #4c8dcb;
    border-radius: 24px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon">                        
        <path id="icon" d="M11.933 13.069c0 0 7.059-5.094 6.276-10.924-0.017-0.127-0.059-0.213-0.112-0.268-0.054-0.055-0.137-0.098-0.263-0.115-5.697-0.801-10.674 6.422-10.674 6.422-4.318-0.517-4.004 0.344-5.974 5.076-0.377 0.902 0.234 1.213 0.904 0.959 0.67-0.252 2.148-0.811 2.148-0.811l2.59 2.648c0 0-0.546 1.514-0.793 2.199s0.055 1.311 0.938 0.926c4.624-2.016 5.466-1.694 4.96-6.112zM12.942 7.153c-0.598-0.613-0.598-1.604 0-2.217 0.598-0.611 1.567-0.611 2.166 0s0.598 1.603 0 2.217c-0.599 0.611-1.569 0.611-2.166 0z"></path>
    </svg>
```